# Online character set converter unknown

Tags: character-encoding

Folks,
  Came across this, and dont quite know the answer.  What is the character set used here, and how can i convert a sample message into similar set online somewhere?

original string:

```
Strike Back
```

result string:

```
§ƭřïƙè ßáçƙ
```

What character set is this?

Answer (score 1):

That's simply a "leetifier", or "13375p34k converter" or whatever else they're called. It simply changes letters to similar looking letters based on a usually hardcoded lookup table. That's all. This has nothing to do with character sets or encodings at all.

Comment: Unfortunately leetifier doesnt seem right, but i think we're on the right path.  This must be some other tool.  Does anyone know?

Comment: If i use http://www.brenz.net/services/l337Maker.asp, the `Strike Back ` converts to `$7R1|<3 b4(|<`, not the `§ƭřïƙè ßáçƙ` as expected.  must be some other tool.  anyone know?

Comment: Yes, it's *some other tool*, but exactly the same idea. It's just using some other characters as substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Anser is here, Pseudolocalization

http://www.pseudolocalize.com/